# Passing value to state using react-select

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-select

I'm new to react and trying to learn on my own. I started using react-select to create a dropdown on a form and now I'm trying to pass the value of the option selected. My state looks like this.

```
this.state = {
  part_id: "",
  failure: ""
};
```

Then in my render

```
const {
  part_id,
  failure
} = this.state;
```

My form looks has 2 fields

```
<FormGroup>
  <Label for="failure">Failure</Label>
  <Input
    type="text"
    name="failure"
    placeholder="Failure"
    value={failure}
    onChange={this.changeHandler}
    required
    />
  </FormGroup>
  <FormGroup>
  <Label for="part_id">Part</Label>
  <Select
    name="part_id"
    value={part_id}
    onChange={this.changeHandler}
    options={option}
  />
  </FormGroup>
```

the `changeHandler` looks like this

```
changeHandler = e => {
  this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
};
```

The change handler works fine for the input but the Select throws error saying cannot read property name.  I went through the API docs and came up with something like this for the Select onChange

```
onChange={part_id => this.setState({ part_id })}
```

which sets the part_id as a label, value pair. Is there a way to get just the value? and also how would I implement the same with `multiselect`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The return of `react-select` onChange event and the value props both have  the type as below

**event / value**:

```
null | {value: string, label: string} | Array<{value: string, label: string}>
```

So what the error means is that you can't find an attribute of null (not selected),  or any attributes naming as `name` (you need `value` or `label`)

For multiple selections, it returns the sub-list of options.

You can find the related info in their [document](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select)

```
const options = [
  { value: 'chocolate', label: 'Chocolate' },
  { value: 'strawberry', label: 'Strawberry' },
  { value: 'vanilla', label: 'Vanilla' },
];
```

### Update

#### For your situation (single selection)

- option having type as above

```
const option = [
  {value: '1', label: 'name1'},
  {value: '2', label: 'name2'}
]
```

- state save selected `value` as `id`

```
changeHandler = e => {
  this.setState({ part_id: e ? e.value : '' });
};
```

- pick selected option item via saved `id`

```
  <Select
    name="part_id"
    value={option.find(item => item.value === part_id)}
    onChange={this.changeHandler}
    options={option}
  />
```

#### For multiple selections

- state save as id array

```
changeHandler = e => {
  this.setState({ part_id: e ? e.map(x => x.value) : [] });
};
```

- pick via filter

```
  <Select
    isMulti // Add this props with value true
    name="part_id"
    value={option.filter(item => part_id.includes(item.value))}
    onChange={this.changeHandler}
    options={option}
  />
```

Comment: So how would you go about getting just the value? I tried e.value which does give me the selected options value but if i try to set it to part_id nothing gets set

Comment: @JustinS, to extract `value`, you can do this: `onChange = ({ value: part_id }) => this.setState({ part_id })`. But take **note**, `value` prop for `Select` would require the options to have `label` and `value` pair.

Comment: @JosephD. Yes, and that's what I mentioned in the answer, the event may be `null`

Comment: @JosephD. the way you mentioned does work but then I select an option its doesnt show as selected just sets the value for part_id. The select just sticks with the default placeholder message

Comment: But, it changes the previous state? How to make it to save the previous state and further add new selections?

Comment: Hey keikai, I have approximately same problem like this question, I wanted to pass my react-select values to the backend which i am unable to do so, you can check the question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70921035/is-there-any-method-to-pass-multiple-selected-option-value-to-mongodb-using-reac?noredirect=1#comment125668589_70921035 and also check the codesandbox to get the idea that which data i want to sent to the backend through api. here's the link  codesandbox.io/s/crazy-wilbur-its1d?file=/src/App.js:0-811

Answer (score 0):

`onChange` function is a bit different in `react-select`

It passes array of selected values, you may get first one like

```
 onChange={([selected]) => {
    // React Select return object instead of value for selection
    // return { value: selected };
    setValue(selected)
 }}
```

Comment: Notice that if the `select` component doesn't have the props `isMulti` or its value is `false`. It won't return an array.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the above solutions but some of these solutions does update the state but it doesn't gets rendered on the Select value instantly.

Herewith a demo example:

```
this.state = {
          part_id: null,
        };

handleUpdate = (part_id) => {
    this.setState({ part_id: part_id.value }, () =>
        console.log(`Option selected:`, this.state.part_id)
    );
};

const priceOptions = [
    { value: '999', label: 'Item One' },
    { value: '32.5', label: 'Item Two' },
    { value: '478', label: 'Item Three' }
]

<Select
    onChange={this.handleUpdate}
    value={priceOptions.find(item => item.value === part_id)}
    options={priceOptions}
    placeholder={<div>Select option</div>}
/>
```