# Is there any method to pass multiple selected option value to MongoDB using React JS?

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I want to pass the selected option value to my back end using React Select. First I want to select option from React Select then I want to store into the usestate from where i am sending it to the database.

The code look like:

```
const options = [
    { value: 'AUD', label: 'AUD' },
    { value: 'CAD', label: 'CAD' },
    { value: 'CHF', label: 'CHF' },
]
export default function MemberInformation() {
    const { t } = useTranslation();

    const value2 = useContext(DataContext);
    const [currency, setCurrency] = value2.currency;
    const[favcur,setFavCur]=useState([]);
     const[memberData,setMemberData]=useState([]);
    const [member,setMember]=useState({_id:"",name:"",prefCurrency:[]})
         var name,valueV;
        const handleInputs=e=>{
          console.log("Updated ",member)
          name=e.target.name;
          valueV=e.target.value;
          setMember({...member,[name]:valueV})
          if (name == "prefCurrency")
          {
            setFavCur(e);
            setMember({...member,[name]:valueV})
            setCurrency(e);
          }
        }
        const postData= ()=>{
          setMemberData({...memberData,...member})
          const { _id,name,prefCurrency}=member;
          var UpdatedMemInfo ={_id,name,,prefCurrency};
          axios.put('/memberInfoUpdate', UpdatedMemInfo)
          .then( res => {
            alert('Updated successfully!');
           }   
          )
          .catch(err => {
            console.log(err.response);
            alert('An error occurred! Try submitting the form again.');
          });
       } 
useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchBooks() {
          const response = await fetch('/memberinfo');
          const json = await response.json();
          setMemberData(json.memberLogin);
          setMember(json.memberLogin);
      }
      fetchBooks();
  },[]);
return (
<div>
 <Row >
                  <Col ><Form.Text className="text-muted">{t('Name')}</Form.Text></Col>
                  <Col><Form.Control size="sm" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter Name" value={member.name} onChange={e=>handleInputs(e)}/></Col>
              </Row>
 <Row >
                  <Col ><Form.Text className="text-muted">{t('Preferred Currency')}</Form.Text></Col>
                  <Col>
                  <Select options={options} placeholder="Select Currency" isMulti name="prefCurrency" value={member.prefCurrency}  onChange={handleInputs} />
                   </Col>
              </Row>   
</div>
 )
}
```

The error is that "Cannot read properties of undefined name" and page appears blank. When i want to select any option value it does not select anything from the options data.
`preferred Currency(prefCurrency)` is basically an array type in mongoose schema.
It looks like:
[image]

How can this issue be solved? , how can i pass multiple selected option value to the MongoDB back end?

Comment: In select you are giving options as an array of object where as select value is member.prefCurrency which an array please change prefCurrency to object with fields label and value than the dropdown will appear

Comment: No it doesn't work... The dropdown is appearing the problem is that  if i select any value from dropdown it is not selecting.

Comment: The `react-select` `Select` component's `onChange` handler doesn't take an `onChange` event object if I'm not mistaken. I think you'll need a separate handler for it from the one used for the text input used in the form control. Think you could create a *running* codesandbox demo that reproduces the issue you face?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-wilbur-its1d?file=/src/App.js you can try the code here. I actually want to store the values selected by user which is a object or arrays (you can see in the console, after running in the code) into the mongoDB as you can see in the picture above the type of prefCurrency field. But i couldnt find any particular guide for it that how can i store that object consisting of array of values into the MongoDB.

Comment: Did you save your changes to your sandbox? I see only the basic React template code.

Comment: Yes i had saved it. https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-wilbur-its1d?file=/src/App.js:0-811 check now

Comment: Sorry, just saw that you'd updated. The code in the sandbox is a little different than that in your question. So you've no issue getting the array of multiple selected values? Is the issue with submitting the selections to your DB?

Comment: yes, how can i submit the selected values to the backend. how to pass the array of objects to the api?